# XSL numbering at different levels

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML text document that looks like this:

```
<corpus>
 <deposition>
  <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
  <text>
   <seg type="not_foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
     adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices consequat facilisis. 
     Suspendisse a odio<note>foo note</note> in lobortis. Aenean 
     non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
   <seg type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
     velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note>foo note</note> purus. Praesent 
     aliquam viverra tellus in condimentum.</seg>
   </text>
 </deposition>
 <deposition>
  <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
  <text>
    <seg type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
     natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note>foo note</note> montes, 
     nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
    <seg type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
     Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam pellentesque 
     malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
   </text>
 </deposition>
</corpus>
```

I am adding footnote numbers to it in preparation to print, doing some preprocess using XSL 3.0 on Saxon. The target output adds `<footnote/>` plus increment number on two conditions, `seg[@type='foo'] | note`. The numbers reset to zero for each `deposition`. The result should look like this:

```
<corpus>
 <deposition>
  <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
  <text>
   <seg type="not_foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
     adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices consequat facilisis. 
     Suspendisse a odio<note>some note</note><footnote>1</footnote> in lobortis. Aenean 
     non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
   <seg type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
     velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note>some note</note><footnote>2</footnote> purus. Praesent 
     aliquam viverra tellus in condimentum.</seg><footnote>3</footnote>
   </text>
 </deposition>
 <deposition>
  <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
  <text>
    <seg type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
     natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note>some note</note><footnote>1</footnote> montes, 
     nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg><footnote>2</footnote>
    <seg type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
     Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam pellentesque 
     malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg></seg><footnote>3</footnote>
   </text>
 </deposition>
</corpus>
```

I am using the following to copy and insert the `<footnote>`with number:

```
<xsl:template match="seg[@type='foo'] | note">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy><footnote><xsl:number count="seg[@type='foo'] | note" from="deposition" format="1" level="any"/></footnote>
</xsl:template>
```

However, the result is not what I expected. It seems this template, in terms of assigning numbers, is treating the `seg` element first, and then anything inside the `seg` second? Like layers? In the case of the first `deposition` it results in this new XML:

```
<deposition>
  <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
  <text>
   <seg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
     adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices consequat facilisis. 
     Suspendisse a odio<note>some note</note><footnote>2</footnote> in lobortis. Aenean 
     non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
   <seg type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
     velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note>some note</note><footnote>3</footnote> purus. Praesent 
     aliquam viverra tellus in condimentum.</seg><footnote>1</footnote>
   </text>
 </deposition>
```

This means the footnotes are not in 'real' (or 'printable') order.

Not sure what is causing this. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It's hard to test because you don't have a complete or verifiable example, but `type` appears to be an attribute so wouldn't all occurrences of `seg[type='foo']` need to be `seg[@type='foo']`? Also, maybe it should be `seg[@type='foo']/note` (in both the template match and the count) unless you really do want to count both elements and also output `footnote` elements on `note` and `seg`.

Comment: I've updated for the typo on `@type`. Regarding the second comment, please look again at the output and where the `footnote`goes. It goes on all `note` and after `seg`where `@type=foo`. The two are not interdependent. Thank you.

Comment: I see that now. :-) When xsl:number counts the `seg[@type='foo']`, it's correctly giving you `<footnote>1</footnote>` because that's the first `seg[@type='foo']` in that `deposition`. You're probably going to need to count descendant `note`'s and add them. I'll see if I can work up a solution in a little while. (If someone else doesn't beat me to it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken a different approach, it uses a first transformation step to add empty `footnote` elements and a second transformation step to number these using `xsl:number`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:mode name="add-footnotes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="footnotes">
      <!-- populating variable by pushing the global context item's child node through the mode named 'add-footnotes' -->
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-footnotes"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="seg[@type = 'foo'] | note" mode="add-footnotes">
      <!-- delegating copying of the element to the identity transformation -->
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <footnote/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$footnotes/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="footnote">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number level="any" from="deposition"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbe/1

Comment: Nice! +1 However I think you pasted the wrong link for your sample.

Comment: I didn't realise that one could create a new element and then refer to the new element in the self-same stylesheet? This opens up ideas I didn't know of. It's a brilliant workaround. (Also, your code is here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/5 . Your test code was not 'saved' to a new URL)

Comment: @DanielHaley, sorry, I posted the wrong URL, now corrected.

Comment: @MartinHonnen In your code you've introduced two things which, while they work, I don't understand why they work. Could you add some text /comments to go over the reasoning for  `<xsl:mode name="add-footnotes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` (why do we need this when there is already a general `on-no-match`?) and `<xsl:next-match/>` (why this vs. `apply-templates`)? I ask because I have to integrate this into a large stylesheet (which is too cumbersome to post here) and I'm wary of breaking things I don't understand. Thanks very much.

Comment: Sorry, adding one other item as last comment was not editable: <xsl:apply-templates mode="add-footnotes"/> is added inside `<xsl:variable name="footnotes">`. The reasoning is unclear to me.

Comment: Your code and Daniel's did spell out the identity transformation template twice, that is not necessary, you can write it once and then "call" it using `<xsl:next-match/>` in XSLT 2, and in XSLT 3 you do not even have to write it as a template but it suffices to use `on-no-match="shallow-copy"` on the `xsl:mode`. So that `<xsl:next-match/>` in the template for `seg[@type = 'foo'] | note` is simply my XSLT 3 way of saying "copy this".

Comment: The `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` is no "general" directive, rather it sets up the identity transformation for the unnamed mode. To set it up for the other mode I used (named `add-footnotes`), I have to declare `<xsl:mode name="add-footnotes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` separately.

Comment: To populate the global variable `footnotes` with the result of running the input through the mode named `add-footnotes`, the `<xsl:apply-templates mode="add-footnotes"/>` is necessary. It basically does what I said, it transforms the input using the templates for the mode named `add-footnotes`. That result is then the value of the variable and that variable is then pushed through the unnamed mode in `<xsl:apply-templates select="$footnotes/node()"/>`.

Comment: I've posted a followup question using your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123059/xsl-numbering-using-two-different-sets-simultaneously . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this with `xsl:number`.

The only way I can think of really is to count the preceding `seg`/`note`, add 1 (for self), and add any descendant `note`.

Preceding is not very efficient though so hopefully I'm overlooking something and you'll get a better answer.

Example...

**XML Input** (added an additional `note` for testing)

```
<corpus>
    <deposition>
        <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
        <text>
            <seg type="not_foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices consequat facilisis. 
                Suspendisse a odio<note>foo note</note> in lobortis. Aenean 
                non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
            <seg type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
                velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note>foo note</note> purus. Praesent 
                aliquam viverra tellus<note>another note</note> in condimentum.</seg>
        </text>
    </deposition>
    <deposition>
        <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
        <text>
            <seg type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note>foo note</note> montes, 
                nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
            <seg type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
                Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam pellentesque 
                malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
        </text>
    </deposition>
</corpus>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (this is also valid 1.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="seg[@type='foo']|note">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="dep" select="generate-id(ancestor::deposition)"/>
    <footnote>
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="count((preceding::seg[@type='foo']|preceding::note)[generate-id(ancestor::deposition)=$dep]) + 1 + count(.//note)"/>
    </footnote>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<corpus>
   <deposition>
      <deposition-title>Praesent vitae</deposition-title>
      <text>
         <seg type="not_foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices consequat facilisis. 
                Suspendisse a odio<note>foo note</note>
            <footnote>1</footnote> in lobortis. Aenean 
                non dui scelerisque, rutrum est at, cursus sem.</seg>
         <seg type="foo">Ut pharetra bibendum ipsum, portitor 
                velit pharetra quis. Aeneano<note>foo note</note>
            <footnote>2</footnote> purus. Praesent 
                aliquam viverra tellus<note>another note</note>
            <footnote>3</footnote> in condimentum.</seg>
         <footnote>4</footnote>
      </text>
   </deposition>
   <deposition>
      <deposition-title>Elementum arcu non</deposition-title>
      <text>
         <seg type="foo">Curabitur pulvinar leo eget. Orci varius 
                natoque penatibus et magnis dis<note>foo note</note>
            <footnote>1</footnote> montes, 
                nascetur ridiculus mus.</seg>
         <footnote>2</footnote>
         <seg type="not_foo">Morbi vehicula dolor bibendum enim mollis lobortis. 
                Nulla rutrum vel diam vel posuere. Aliquam pellentesque 
                malesuada elit sed tempor.</seg>
      </text>
   </deposition>
</corpus>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, thank you. Although it feels somewhat like Inception :) I mean to say that if, for whatever reason, I find elements 'nested' further, say something within a `note`that needs a `<footnote>` I would need to go through and wrap the generate id in another generate id - I see that getting very difficult to manage!

Comment: @idjet - Yeah it would be a mess. And slow. If I come up with another idea, I'll post back.

Comment: @idjet - I added another option.

Comment: @idjet - Also, in the first example, if you wanted to add a footnote to a child of `note`, you wouldn't have to wrap the generate-id in another generate-id. Let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems however that this solution is dependent on there only being two `seg`, one having a `footnote` (effectively hardcoded solution). Have a look at the test here where I added some variation -  third seg which also needs a footnote. http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a

Comment: @idjet - Yep you're right. I'm going to delete my second option. Here's an example of adding a `footnote` to a child of `note` (I used `eton`) without wrapping the generate-id: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5a/3